# How to add a <body> element to a manually generated Document?

Tags: html, jsoup

I'm attempting to use JSoup to generate HTML from nothing i.e. not parsing a file, but rather generating HTML output in order to display the data in an object.  I'm brand new to JSoup and have been looking for some examples of how to use it to generate HTML but haven't found much useful content for this specific task so I've been tinkering, but with minimal success.  Here's some [non-working] code:

```
package jsouptest;  

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;  

public class JSoupTest {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Document doc = new Document("");  

        Element headline = doc.body().appendElement("h1").text("Some text");
        Element pTag = doc.body().appendElement("p").text("some text ...");
        Element span = pTag.prependElement("span").text("MoarTxt");
    }

}
```

This line:

```
Element headline = doc.body().appendElement("h1").text("Some text");
```

Throws a `NullPointerException`. Through some trial and error, I believe that I've determined the problem is that `doc.body()` isn't defined anywhere.  I assumed (apparently, incorrectly) that a newly instantiated `Document` would come with an empty body.  That doesn't seem to be the case, however.  I can't figure out if I need to instantiate a new body element.  I've read through the javadoc for the `Document` class but don't see any kind of factory or setter methods that would generate the body element for me.

Recommendations for resources beyond the [JSoup API JavadDoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) that might be helpful are welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append a `<body>` element to a newly created document, in its simplest form, use:

```
doc.appendElement("body");
```

Heres' your full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Document doc = new Document("");
    doc.appendElement("body");

    Element headline = doc.body().appendElement("h1").text("Some text");
    Element pTag = doc.body().appendElement("p").text("some text ...");
    Element span = pTag.prependElement("span").text("MoarTxt");

    System.out.println(doc);
}
```

Output:

```
<body>
 <h1>Some text</h1>
 <p><span>MoarTxt</span>some text ...</p>
</body>
```

As for documentation, I believe you are already there, their official site is the best place. I'd also take a look at their [cookbok](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/).